# Give permission to AWS Lambda to List all SNS topics

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

I have a `cloudformation` template to create a lambda function and an SNS topic. The lambda function does some processing and publishes the result to the SNS topic.

To get the SNS topic's ARN, I'm using the `boto3.client('sns').list_topics()` function and then searching for the SNS topic name that I've set in the template.

But calling the `list_topics()` API is giving me the following error:

`An error occurred (AuthorizationError) when calling the ListTopics operation: User: arn:aws:sts::136732452473:assumed-role/test/severless-btc-update-PriceUpdateFunction-B38KNZMCBGB is not authorized to perform: SNS:ListTopics on resource: arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:136732452473:*`

How can I add the ListTopics permission to my lambda resource in the cloudformation template YAML file?

This is my cloudformation.yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Bitcoin daily update


Parameters:
  PhoneNumber:
    Type: String
    Description: The phone number recipient of the update, in E.164 (e.g. +919876123456) format.
  UTCHour:
    Type: String
    Default: 3
    Description: The hour at which to send the update, in the UTC time zone.

Resources:
  PriceUpdateFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: main.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Timeout: 5
      CodeUri: main.py
      Environment:
        Variables:
          PHONE_NUMBER: !Ref PhoneNumber
      Events:
        ScheduledEvent:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: !Join [' ', ['cron(0', !Ref UTCHour, '* * ? *)']]
      Policies:
        - SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
          TopicName: !GetAtt SNSTopic.TopicName
  SNSTopic:
    Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    Properties:
      TopicName: "sendSMS"
      DisplayName: "BitcoinPriceTopic"
      Subscription:
        -
          Endpoint: !Ref PhoneNumber
          Protocol: "sms"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the Lambda execution role and assign the function the appropriate permissions. There should be a `Role` property of `AWS::Serverless::Function`

`Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn`

Then create the referenced role in your template:

```
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: {Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]}
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: SNSPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - "SNS:ListTopic" 
              Resource: ['*']
```

Tweak the permission in the `Action` section as needed.